# After change location, scroll to element with animation

Tags: jquery

when I click on `<a id="cityAaaHref">Link</a>` i want to change location, and scroll with animation to section.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#cityAaaHref').click(function () {
    var selector = $(this).data('selector');
    if (window.location.pathname == "/aaa/") {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + selector).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }else{
        window.location = "../aaa#city";
        //how to here set animation after location change
    }
})
```

IF statement working exactly how I need
The only problem is with ELSE state, here I change location and show this section, but I want to change location and then show scrolling animation to this section.

I hope you understand. Thnx

Comment: Your code redirect to another page `../aaa` so you need to put a code in second page that after page load get `hash` value from URL and animate to element has that hash (`#city`)

Comment: I need to scroll only if I click on this link. If I came to this `aaa` page on a regular way, I don't need scroll to any element. How to check if I came from this link or regular way? Thnx  @Mohammad

Comment: When you used `#city` at the end of URL, browser automatically scroll to element has id `city` after page load, but you need to add animation to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the **aaa** page you can do this logic:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.hash === "#city") {
        //do something
    }
});
```

If having a hash of `"#city"` does not necessarily mean the animation is to be executed, then in your code you can mark the animation as needed into `localStorage`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cityAaaHref').click(function () {
        var selector = $(this).data('selector');
        if (window.location.pathname == "/aaa/") {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#" + selector).offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }else{
            localStorage.setItem('aaa', 'animation');
            window.location = "../aaa#city";
            //how to here set animation after location change
        }
    });
});
```

and then at the other page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('aaa') === 'animation') {
        //do something
    }
});
```